# How to convert a JSON string into a normal string in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I use SwiftyJSON to get data in JSON format from an API. This data is stored into a variable which I want to convert into a String.

I have the following:

```
func parseJSON() {

    let path2 = NSURL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5")
    let jsonData2 = NSData(contentsOfURL: path2!) as NSData!
    let readableJSON2 = JSON(data: jsonData2, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

    numberOfRows = readableJSON2["name"].count //maybe hardcode this in the future?

    let id = readableJSON2["id"]
    NSLog("\(id)")
    let name = readableJSON2["name"]
    NSLog("\(name)")
    let weight = readableJSON2["weight"]
    NSLog("\(weight)")
    let height = readableJSON2["height"]
    NSLog("\(height)")


    idArray.append(id)
}
```

Note that the idArray is a String array:

```
var idArray = [String]()
```

The NSLog("(id)") returns a 5. I want this 5 to be a string, but I don't know how. I tried the following:

```
var id = readableJSON2["id"].string as String!
```

but this results into a nil..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to typecast the value rather than force unwrap it as a String, as so:

```
var id = String(readableJSON2["id"])
```

Let me know if that works.